# In ARM, how do I include optional parameterised object in array collection?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have an ARM template which takes a parameter that defines an access policy for a KeyVault. The KeyVault definition already includes an access policy. I need to append the parameter to the access policy collection if it exists. I can't find a way to do this that works when the value is set and when it's not.

The following works when the parameter is set but not when it's empty. I need it to be optional.

```
"accessPolicies": [
    {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('myazfunc')), '2019-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
        "permissions": {
            "secrets": [
                "get",
                "list"
            ]
        }
    },
    "[parameters('additionalAccessPolicy')]"
]
```

Anyone know how I can achieve this? I feel like I've tried everything. Hoping I've missed something.

Answer (score 1):

to achieve something like this you can use an `if()` function together with a `concat()` function, so only concat the optional array to the existing array if some condition is met.

so you would have the default and optional arrays as variables and do something like:

```
"accessPolicies": "[if(something, variables('default'), concat(variables('default'), variables('optional'))]"
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I can't use `reference()` in a variable and I haven't figured out how I can put an array literal within the if statement to avoid using a variable.

Comment: well, i dont think you can do that, i mean you can try with the `json('[put_something_here]')` function, but I dont that is a viable solution. use nested templates to construct the value and use that in the if statement